# Creating recursively a function gaining variables each iteration in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to create a function `foo()` which gives as output another function. This output function is the sum of exponentials (or whatever) with a free parameter a<sub>i</sub> each time. This output function should have as parameters all the a<sub>i</sub> plus a free variable.

Example:

Calling `foo(3)` should output a function equivalent to `lambda t,a1,a2,a3: exp(a1*t)+exp(a2*t)+exp(a3*t)`

I tried to programm it like that:

```
def foo(n):
  fh = lambda t,A1:exp(A1*t)
  def fg(j):
    if (j==1):
      return fh
    else:
      return lambda t,A1,A2:fg(j-1)(t,A1)+fh(t,A2)
  return fg(n)
```

but it is obviously wrong. I remarked that `foo(n)` can be obtained via recusion by "doing" something like `lambda t,a1,...,a(n): foo(n-1)(t,a1,...,a(n-1))+exp(a(n)*t)` as iteration, but I didn't manage to do it in a simple way...

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion. You can simply define a function, that takes an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def f(t, *a):
    return sum(exp(x * t) for x in a)
```